# Cannot add item to a list initialized in other class

Tags: c#, list, initialization

Friends, I would like to know why following code works for `List<int>` and not for `List<string>`. When I initialize list in getter of property then it does not work. If I initialize in constructor it works and also if I create list in the calling class it works.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private List<int> _ints;
    private static List<string> _strings;

    public MyClass()
    {
        _ints = new List<int>();
    }
    public List<int> Ints
    {
        get
        {
            return _ints;
        }
        set
        {
            _ints = value;
        }
    }

    public List<string> Strings
    {
        get
        {
            return _strings ?? new List<string>();
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        MyClass mc = new MyClass();
        // This works
        // mc.Ints = new List<int>();
        // This works           
        mc.Ints.Add(1);
        // This does not
        mc.Strings.Add("Krishna");
   } 
}
```

Comment: you never assign `_strings` to an instantiated `List<string>`

Comment: You aren't accessing an initialised list of strings, look at the difference between how you've interacted with `Ints` and how you've interacted with `Strings`...

Comment: An additional question? Why is `_strings` `static`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `mc.Strings.Add("Krishna");` wont work because you return new `List<string>` every time you call `mc.Strings`. To explain it in more details :

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass(); // create new instance of MyClass and store it in the "mc" variable
mc // Direct call to the instance
    .Strings // Direct call to MyClass Strings property
         // inside Strings property :
         // return _strings ?? new List<string>();
         // meaning that if "_strings" member field is null
         // return new instance of that property's type
    .Add("abc"); // adds "abc" to the "forgotten" instance of List<string>
```

Simply speaking you're doing the same as you would call :

```
new List<string>().Add("abc");
```

To get this fixed you can use one-liner ( which you obviously tried ) like this one :

```
return _strings ?? ( _strings = new List<string>() );
```

Or use if statement :

```
if(_strings == null)
    _strings = new List<string>();

return _strings;
```

Comment: Thanks Rogalski. I was under the impression that return _strings ??  new List<string>() ); will retain the object. Looks like it is always creating new object.

Answer (score 4):

You aren't initializing the variable on the getter, if the variable is null you create a new list but you don't store the reference to it.

Change your code to this:

```
public List<string> Strings
{
    get
    {
        if(_strings == null)
            _strings = new List<string>();

        return _strings;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `_strings` being static makes this not thread safe. Better initialization as a singleton would be through `private static readonly _strings = new List<string>()`.

Comment: Yes, of course, but the question is not 'how to  implement better code' but 'why when I initialize the list on the getter it doesn't works'.

Comment: But imagine your answer enlightens thousands of developers which all use your code in exactly this case and then they start noticing strange, hard to reproduce effects and errors in their concurrent web applications ;-)

Comment: And then imagine someone comes here, sees that and then thinks it's not possible to initialize a variable in a getter and he quits programming because he can't do what he wants... :D

Comment: You don't but the programmer quitting does.. Also I have no problem if someone uses this code and it explodes to him because he declared statically a collection which shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Because `List<int>` initializes on the constructor of your class where as `List<string>` does not.  Try:

```
public MyClass()
{
        _ints = new List<int>();
        _strings=new List<string>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your '_strings' list always null. If you call 'get' of 'Strings' property, you always create and return new list instance.

```
    get
    {
        // if '_strings' is null, then create new instance of list
        return _strings ?? new List<string>();
    }
```

You need to use this:

```
    get
    {           
        // If '_strings' is null, then create new instance of list and assign new instance to '_strings'
        return _strings ?? (_strings = new List<string>());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inline variant of Gusman's answer, using some of the nice features of C# 6.0

```
public List<string> Strings => _strings ?? (_strings = new List<string>());
```

Answer (score -1):

An FYI, to completely understand the problem, you could've put a breakpoint on this line:

```
return _strings ?? new List<string>();
```

You would've seen `_strings` is always null and you need to initialize it as answers above tell you so :)

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment.

Comment: @Gusman I need 50 reputation for a comment, and since I wanted to help him..I had to leave an answer. Next time I should not even try to help a guy out? Thanks for the downvote -.-

Comment: Glad you liked it. Read the posting rules before complaining, comments as answers are totally forbidden on S.O.

Comment: Techinically, I gave an answer about it not being initialized, but w/e